# Marshal.Copy()

Tags: c#

Копирует данные из управляемого массива в указатель неуправляемой памяти или из указателя неуправляемой памяти в управляемый массив. Т.е. например из IntPtr в int, а также можно из int в IntPtr.

```
float[] fin;
IntPtr pin;
```

...

```
Marshal.Copy(fin,0,pin,n*2);
```

Как я понял в данном случае происходит копирование данных из управляемого массива в указатель неуправляемой памяти. Почему в качестве параметров "0" и "n*2"?
Как осуществить копирование данных из указателя неуправляемой памяти в управляемый массив?

И какой это язык? найти не смог

Comment: Язык C# точно!, справка MSDN, поиск в VS по Framework поможет, там всё написано!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntPtr - явно указывает на C# или C++, но не на C. Я б сказал, что скорее всего C#. Из-за float[].

Касательно ф-ции - смотрим [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146629(VS.80).aspx). Ясно написано, что 0 - это индекс начального элемента, с которого начинать копирование. А n*2 - длина копируемой области.